# PHP compare string for duplicatation

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have an array like so:

```
   array{
    [39] => src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
    [111] => src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/code.js"
    [55] => src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/yui.js"
    [1015] => src="wp-content/uploads/website.jpg"
   }
```

**Qeustion**

What is the best way to find the difference of string ?

What I mean is to check if there are any duplicates.

`src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/` is repeated twice.

so if I then had an array like this:

```
array{
    [39] => src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
    [55] => src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/yui.js"
    [1015] => src="wp-content/uploads/website.jpg"
   }
```

`http://www.` is repeated twice.

so the Idea is to compare the string with another and find something that is duplicated and push it to an array ... thats all that I need :)

I am not saying it could be possible, but it would be nice if it could be :)

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more what you need. Have you tried with regular expressions? You can match duplicates and select them as groups to work on them later...

Comment: Are you matching only from the beginning?

Comment: So you want to determine unique string prefixes?  [`strncmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php)?

Comment: @mellamokb It may not always be the case, [if on second array] google had secure `https:` then the result would be `://www.` is a duplicate :)

Comment: What about `js` duplicated in `jsapi` and `yui.js`?

Comment: how long does the string have to be before it can be compared/considered a duplicate?

Comment: Also you are going to find `/` quite frequent, this is a bit absurd.

Comment: well the above is space splitted so not very long, this is just a concept I am working on, :)

Comment: @steve you can always skip single characters with a simple if statement

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have `wp-content/` in that list?

Comment: Can we all go conform that this question does not specify exactly what a difference/duplicate is? If so I suggest to close because it's highly vague to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community, feel free to optimize the code. I quickly wrote this out.

```
function findStrDuplicate($str1, $str2)
{
    $duplicate = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < min(strlen($str1), strlen($str2)); $i++) {
        if($str1[$i] != $str2[$i]) {
            break;
        }
        $duplicate .= $str1[$i];
    }

    return $duplicate;
}

function findArrayPrefixDuplicate($array)
{
    $duplicatesArray = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array) - 1; $i++) {
        for($j = $i+1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
            $dup = findStrDuplicate($array[$i], $array[$j]);
            if(!empty($dup)) {
                $duplicatesArray[] = $dup;
            }
        }
    }

    return array_unique($duplicatesArray);
}

$data = array(
    'src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"',
    'src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/code.js"',
    'src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/yui.js"',
    'src="wp-content/uploads/website.jpg"'
);

// Remove src="..."

$data = array_map(function ($val) {
    return substr($val, 5, strlen($val) - 1);
}, $data);

$result = findArrayPrefixDuplicate($data);

var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array
  0 => string 'http://www.' (length=11)
  2 => string 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/' (length=41)
```

Comment: this is alot more than I wanted :) so thumbs up :) thnk u

Answer (score 0):

The following link should help with this:  http://www.rogerethomas.com/b/14/php-search-string-for

You just need to change the else output to add it to the array and add a while loop in there if you are reiterating over multiple entries

Comment: If I knew the `$x` there wouldn't be any point asking the question as I have lol, `str_replace();` would have done the job :)

Comment: oh, you are looking at finding the diff and then using that in order to find the dupe, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will probably want to take a look at the suffix tree data structure. Take a look at this post for some ideas:

[Fast String Search With Suffix Trees](http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/)